# Javascript function won't load first time on a page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a Javascript function that uses ajax that is called when a button is clicked.

It works fine if you go to the page a second time but for some reason won't work the first time on the page.

I've tried adding a `window.onload, document.onload,document.ready etc` to it but those immediately call the function and causes errors since the variables arent instantiated yet.

Idk if it's maybe because the button is dynamically created through php or what. 
Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please add your code and we can easily help you.

Comment: You'll have to post the code, or a representative sample, that has the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the DOM is ready, create a click event handler on your button and make your AJAX call there.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/j5c4xjLo/2/

```
$(function() {
  $('#myButtonId').click(function(){
    //AJAX CALL CODE HERE
    console.log('hey.......');
  });
});
```

Comment: sounds like this may work, can't try yet as my server is down :( can I do the same thing but with a class rather than and id? or should I give each one a different id

Comment: $('.myButtonClass').click etc.. if you want to use a class

Comment: i was still having trouble, so i used a variable to force a refresh. thanks for the help